# Regex matches on Url String

Tags: regex

I need some help in working with regex.

I have the following list of urls where I only want to match the first one. What I'm trying to do is exclude all other links except the product url from a site which doesnt have any other slashes. The Product urls pages are just "product-name.aspx"

I have tried the following regex but cant quite master it, as it returns all matches.

```
.*\.aspx
```

Here are examples of the urls. The first one is a product url I want to keep, the other should not be matched.

```
/1-KG-HEAT-PUMP.aspx
/Functions/ShoppingCart/?ReturnUrl=/600MM-SLIDE-OUT-RANGEHOOD-1.aspx
/Functions/ShoppingCart?ReturnUrl=%2f600MM-SLIDE-OUT-RANGEHOOD-3.aspx
/Functions/AddToCart/?AppCode=NTA4Mjk%3d&ReturnUrl=/900W-8-COOKING-FUNCTIONS-1.aspx
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks
Brendan

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a negated character class that prevents any slashes except the leading one:

```
/[^/]*\.aspx
```

This means `/`, then any number of non-slash characters, then `.aspx`

Answer (score 0):

To only match the first result, match on only alpha numeric and dash (-) between / and .aspx

```
 ^/([\w\-]*\.aspx)
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for everyone's responses.  
When I use this it still returns all matched lines as matched. What Im trying to get to is only matching line where there is no subdirectories.  

Perhaps my questions wasnt explicit enough.  
So for example this line:  
/1-KG-HEAT-PUMP.aspx
Would match.  
Whereas this line  
/Functions/ShoppingCart?ReturnUrl=%2f600MM-SLIDE-OUT-RANGEHOOD-3.aspx  
would not be matched  
thanks again brendan

Comment: That is very different than I thought after reading your original post, so my answer now no longer useful. It seems Bohemian's answer is the only correct one then.